# Copiar somente conteúdo da superclasse no java

Tags: java, java-8

Existe uma forma copiar somente o conteúdo da superclasse em uma outra classe de igual tipo através de uma instância de subclasse no Java, sem acessar getters e setters um a um?

Exemplo:

```
public class A {
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    //outros
}

public class B extends A {
   private String age;
}
```

preciso fazer algo como:

```
B objB = new B();
objB.setId(10);
objB.setNome("Jonh Doe");
objB.setAge(21);

A objA = // AQUI COPIAR DE objB apenas o conteúdo da superclasse A
```

Comment: Clonando talvez?

Comment: Eu usei o Clone @Articuno, mas misteriosamente o objeto veio com os atributos da subclasse e a aplicação lançou uma exception pois o hibernate não reconhecia a entidade...

Comment: Tem como colocar o caso de uso disso que está a tentar fazer ?

Comment: A forma mais simples de fazer isso é não usar herança e sim composição. Ou seja, `public class B { private A a; private String age; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde sei, não é possível fazer isso o que quer com orientação a objetos "pura".

Todavia, você pode usar algumas libs que fazem esse trabalho.
Um bom exemplo é a [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).
Com ela você pode fazer a cópia dos valores dos atributos de uma instância do tipo `X` para uma instância de `Y` que será criada pelo ModelMapper:

```
class A {
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    //getters & setters
}

class B extends A {
   private String age;
   //getters & setters
}


class Mapeamento {

    public A fromBToA(B b) {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        return mapper.map(b, A.class);
    }
}
```

O ModelMapper permite configurações mais sofisticadas caso precise (veja documentação).

Comment: Pelo que pude observar, de fato, essa é a solução mais "atraente" existente atualmente.